# Live Streaming and conversation in the stream

Tags: android, ios, mobile, streaming, live

I intend to realise an app and my first trouble is : is it even possible ? Let me explain to you.

The app must allow people to stream live channel that are broadcasting audios. Nothing hard here. The channel's owner can choose which specific people are allowed to listen to his channel (still nothing hard) but also which people can react among them. Yes it must allow people to talk in the audio stream too. In this part it will be like a hangout or skype-like. The stream also has a limited time (1-hour maybe).

So basically the app allow to make live audio stream and people can react in that stream. 
Do you guys have any direction or even intuition in the feasibility of such a thing ? Thanks you.

Comment: If it's all audio and no video, then you'll probably want to look into this: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html -- essentially what you're describing is a glorified VoIP call.

Comment: Ok let me take a look at the link.

Comment: So @NoChinDeluxe this answers to one part of my problem that is how to make the stream and allow many users to connect.

But what about the other part, the part where people can talk back in the stream ? Thus making it a bi-directional stream (or multi-directional in my case) ?